# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

im new in angular i really need help and thanks in advance

```js
constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
 this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
 
 if(token){
  this.interval = setInterval(this.ingameee, 5000);
 }
}

ingameee() {
   this.http.get('http://url.com/api/matchmaking/keepalive?token='+ this.token)
          .subscribe(
              response => {
                  this.dataa = response;
                  this.mod = this.dataa.json().mod;
                  this.playersinqueue = this.dataa.json().playersinqueue;
                  this.region_id = this.dataa.json().region_id;
                  this.party_id = this.dataa.json().party_id;
                  },
              error => console.log(error),
          );

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

keep in mind to use `arrow function` for keeping the context while using **callbacks** because `this`(the context) will change.

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.ingameee(), 5000);
```

Comment: alternatively use: this.interval = setInterval(this.ingameee.bind(this), 5000);